# Editor Privilege?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editing, suggested-edits

Speaking from experience, waiting for a suggested edit to be approved (before 2000 rep.) can be tiring and annoying. So what I want to know is if you guys think the following is a good idea. For those of us (me) who are avid editors, after ~100-150 approved edits, we get a privilege on the site that allows us to immediately publish edits that we make. This is just an idea, and I'd love your feedback or suggestions for improvements on this

Comment: What's with all the downvotes?  The question/suggestion was made in good faith.  Such downvotes intimidate other people from suggesting things here.

Comment: @rclocher3 [Voting is different on meta.](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @EliahKagan Aha, makes sense now, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 19):

Features like this are put behind an experience wall because **we want experience**.
Both technical with the subject matter, and with the system.

150 good edits is equivalent a weekend of contact time for some people. That's not *nearly* enough time to get everything right, or more importantly, for the system to notice a problem (in appropriate edits, etc).

We don't want new users in a position where they can cause lots damage without oversight.